# texlive problems after upgrade to 14.04 from 12.04

Tags: upgrade, eclipse, latex

During upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 I got lots of errors about various items related to TeX.  Most of them reported 'tex-common is not configured' as at least a part of the problem.

When I try to reinstall tex-common, I get the error:  No file name for tex-common:i386

Other side effects of this problem are that I can no longer start Eclipse, and as you would expect Kile and other applications that manipulate LaTeX don't work any more.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Peter, Eclipse is not dependent on `texlive`, if it does not start it is for some other reason. First off: try to remove all the existing packages with a command like `sudo apt-get purge texlive*` and then install it again.

Comment: Didn't work, I'm afraid.  I purged all the textlive packages (and deleted all the configuration files from /etc/texmf/texmf.d as instructed during the purge).  I then tried to reinstall and got vast numbers of error messages like this:

Comment: Your comment is missing the error message. If you are unable to install packages your problem is certainly broader and not related to `texlive` *per se*.

Comment: So I tried to install tex-common, but got the following error:

¿Desea continuar? [S/n] s
Configurando tex-common (4.04) ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... 
updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.s1B6Cu4l
Please include this file if you report a bug.

This file appears to be a binary file, so I can't get any help there.

The error in my previous was followed by vast numbers of other ones all telling me that nothing could be done because text-common was not configured.

Comment: Sorry about missing error messages.  They were all complaining that tex-common was not configured

Comment: From which repository are you installing texlive? You seem to have hit an old bug, check if [this thread at LaTeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64554) helps

Comment: Repository is presumably the 14.04 one.  Actually, I thought I'd fixed the problem by purging tex-common, but now when I start Eclipse, it gets to the "Loading Workbench" splash screen but hangs about 25% of the way through.  No error message from the command line.

Comment: Ha!  Reinstalled tex-common and eclipse starts just fine.  I have to say I find it odd that eclipse appears to depend on tex: but even give that, I find it odd that eclipse installs without tex and doesn't complain about it.  Very strange.  Thanks for all the help received.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge tex-common
sudo update-updmap
sudo updmap-sys --syncwithtrees
sudo updmap-sys
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

During the first command above, pay attention to the list of packages that are removed along with tex-common. In my case it removed `kile` and a lot of other texlive advanced packages. You will need to reinstall them after.